# Tabletop game similar to Civilization, set in Antiquity

Tags: identify-this-game

I played this game a few years ago and suddenly feel the need to find it again.

The board represented most of Europe and North Africa. Each player had an empire and was represented by a historical figure (Julius Cesar, Cleopatra, Hammurabi, etc. I forget who represented the Greeks. Not Alexander the Great). Each empire had some advantage (the Greeks produced 1 extra ship each round).

The map was divided into territories, some with resources which could be exploited. Something like wood, grain, metal, etc.

Can anyone identify what it was?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you thinking of [Mare Nostrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mare_Nostrum_%28board_game%29)?

Comment: I just looked it up on eBay and Amazon - it's darn pricey at $85+!